# Spark + Java - Get Results from a dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a small dataset that has the population data by country on HDFS. I have written the code to parse it and load it into `Dataset<Row>`

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount").setMaster("local");
    SparkContext context = new SparkContext(conf);
    SparkSession sparkSession = new SparkSession(context);

    Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).load(args[1]);
    System.out.println("========== Print Schema ============");
    df.printSchema();
    System.out.println("========== Print Data ==============");
    df.show();
```

The console shows the data correctly -

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|countriesAndTerritories|           location|    continent|population_year|population|
+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|            Afghanistan|        Afghanistan|         Asia|           2020|  38928341|
|                Albania|            Albania|       Europe|           2020|   2877800|
|                Algeria|            Algeria|       Africa|           2020|  43851043|
|                Andorra|            Andorra|       Europe|           2020|     77265|
```

However, I want to get the population of `United States` into an `int` variable.

The query to choose the population is

```
Dataset<String>xdc = df.select(col("population"))
      .where(col("location").equalTo("United States")).limit(1)
```

But how do I get the contents of it into `int` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that:

```
int v = Integer.parseInt(
 df.select(col("population"))
 .where(col("location").equalTo("United States"))
 .limit(1)
 .first()
 .get(0)
 .toString()
);
```